# PostGIS raster - how to populate pixel values by set of points?

Tags: postgis, raster

I have the table "events" with column "point" that contains geometries (points). And I need to fill a raster (already created in table "rasters") using this set of points.
For simplicity BandPixelType is 1BB, default pixel value is 0, and I want it to be 1, if pixel contains at least one point from my table. Raster and geometries have the same SRID (4326).
So, I need something like:
`UPDATE rasters SET rast = ST_SetValue(rast, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lon, lat), 4326), 1)`
but executed with a dataset:
`SELECT point FROM events WHERE ...condition...`

Comment: How many points?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands. At some point - might be millions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is [`ST_SetValues`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetValues.html) which takes an array of [`geomval`](https://postgis.net/docs/geomval.html)

```
raster ST_SetValues(raster rast, integer nband, geomval[] geomvalset, boolean keepnodata=FALSE);
```

> For Variant 5, an array of geomval is used to determine the specific pixels to be set. **If all the geometries in the array are of type POINT or MULTIPOINT, the function uses a shortcut where the longitude and latitude of each point is used to set a pixel directly.** Otherwise, the geometries are converted to rasters and then **iterated through in one pass**. See example Variant 5.

Emphasis added by me. see the docs for an example. Should look like this...

```
UPDATE rasters
SET rast = ST_SetValues(
  rast,
  1,    -- nband
  (
    SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT (point,1)::geomval
      FROM events
      WHERE ...condition
    )
  )
);
```

This may also work..

```
UPDATE rasters
SET rast = ST_SetValues(
  rast,
  1,    -- nband
  (
    SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT (ST_Collect(point),1)::geomval
      FROM events
      WHERE ...condition
    )
  )
);
```

Not sure which will be faster.

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly what I didn't manage - to wrap result of SELECT in ARRAY.

Comment: BTW, in my particular case ST_Collect doesn't affect a query runtime.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way is to compose the array by using `array_agg` function:

```
UPDATE rasters
SET rast = ST_SetValues(
  rast,
  1,    -- nband
  array_agg((e.point, e.value)::geomval)
 )
 FROM events e
 WHERE ...condition;
```

This way you can also define the values based on `events` records and even `JOIN` `rasters` table and `events` table by some criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @evan-carroll for your answer, it helped me quite a bit.

I just want to post this here in case somebody has the same problem as me.

If you want to create a **new raster**, **using an existing raster as reference**, and populate it with **geo-referenced data from a table**, you can proceed as such:

```
create view new_data_raster as
select
--- set values
ST_SetValues(
    --- add a band
    ST_AddBand(
        --- create empty raster with existing raster as reference
        ST_MakeEmptyRaster(r.rast),
        --- set default values to 99
        1, '8BUI', 99, 99
    ),
    --- select band 1
    1,
    (
        SELECT ARRAY(
            --- fill values where needed
            SELECT (d.geom, d.value)::geomval
            FROM data d
            where ... --- optional
        )
    )
) as rast

from reference_raster r
```